# populating a dropdown box with list of users in UserProfile table to delete a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 application where I am trying to add  delete a user functionality for an admin where I should be able to select a user from dropdown list and delete him.

I was able to delete a user by manually typing in a username in a textbox but I wanted to prepopulate a drop down with list of all users.

I started off the functionality using a textbox

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult DeleteUser(UserProfile model)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                /
                try
                {
                    if (model.UserName == null)
                    {
                        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Username required.";
                        return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        var user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "User Does Not exist.";
                            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Membership.DeleteUser(model.UserName);

                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account");
                    }
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }


            return View(model);
        }
```

**DeleteUser.cshtml**

```
@model WhiteBoardApp.Models.UserProfile


@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Account"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ol>
                <li>

                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    <span style="color:red;">@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</span>
                </li>

            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete User" />
            </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

**May I know how I can replace username textbox with a dropdon list with all the usernames?**

Comment: When I used Siplemembership I had to just grab the usernames from the UserProfile DB table, threw them into a viewmodel, then binded them to a dropdown.

Comment: @dev, Are you want to delete the user by user name? Or UserID?

Answer (score 0):

Add ExistingUsers property of type IEnumerable< SelectListItem > in UserProfile class.

Query the database to populate ExistingUsers with the list of users.

Replace '@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)' with '@Html. DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName, Model.ExistingUsers)'.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your DeleteUser.cshtml

```
    @model WhiteBoardApp.Models.UserProfile

    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Account"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <fieldset>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ol>
                    <li>

                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName, new SelectList(GetUserName(), "UserName", "UserName"))
                        <span style="color:red;">@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</span>
                    </li>

                </ol>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete User" />
                </div>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

Write user define function called `GetUserName` to get all the user name from database. In dataValueField and dataTextField mention the user name property like `UserName`

While submitting the page it will pass the selected user name to model

Comment: Thanks and what type of list should the function return?

Comment: @Dev, Return a function using List